# How to query for metadata that is required for a put or a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

2016 exposes the web api endpoint:

```
myorg.com/api/data/v8.1/
```

It is possible to query and filter entities using ODATA:

```
GET myorg.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts?$top=10
```

When using this endpoint to update or create records, **how do we know which fields are required for PUT/POST?**

There's an endpoint that gets metadata:

```
myorg.com/api/data/v8.1/$metadata
```

However, this does not specify whether fields are required for posts/puts against the ../api/data/v8.1 end point.

**Does CRM expose information about which fields are required for updating/creating records?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query metadata for all existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531660/how-to-query-metadata-for-all-existing-fields)